# I'm trying to turn lookup function outcome into text in powerapps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

this is the code

```
LookUp(database, 'id-code' = scannerRes, level).Value
```

and I want the outcome to be a text format. note level is a choice column in a SharePoint list and scannerRes is a var set in a scanner.

plz, let me know what you think.